# How to interpret a simple indirect effect obtained from two separate regressions

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, effect-size, checking

I have a simple question to check my math.

Consider a logistic regression, Model 1, which I'll discuss in terms of probabilities rather than logits to make things simpler. All variables are binary variables.

In Model 1, I find that Covariate1 increases the probability of "success" on my key binary DependentVariable by .26. This Model 1 includes a Covariate2 as well.

But I also think that Covariate2 has an indirect effect on DependentVariable, through its effect on Covariate 1. So I estimate a second logistic regression (Model 2) with Covariate 1 as the dependent variable, including Covariate2 as a covariate. This tells me that Covariate2 increases the probability of "success" on Covariate1 by .03.

My simple question is just to check how I calculate the indirect effect of Covariate 2 on increasing the probability of success on the DependentVariable, specifically through its contribution/share/role in a hypothetical one-level change/increase in Covariate1.

On a first go, I want to do .26*.03 = .01. In other words, 3% of Covariate1's 26% effect on DependentVariable is attributable to Covariate2. Or you could just as well say that a level change in Covariate2 increases the probability of success on the DependentVariable by 1% through its effect on Covariate 2.

Is this right? I have a bad feeling this is incorrect but my brain can't think through why or how this could be done better.

Please note I am aware there are much more sophisticated ways to investigate such a research question--I only wish to check I am doing this basic intuitive calculation most sensibly.